# Unable to use Partial on a generic type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to make a `Map` class containing a mapping that will be set by other classes (for example `CharacterManager`.
Since the content is up to the other classes, I want `Map` to take a generic that will always extend `object`.

For example:

```
// Map.ts
interface MapCellData {
  collides: boolean;
}

class Map<CellData extends object = {}> {
  map!: Array<Array<CellData & MapCellData>>;
}

// CharacterManager.ts
interface CharacterManagerCellData {
  character: null | Character;
}

// And so on...
```

By looking at the type `Array<Array<CellData & MapCellData>>`, you can see that I want each cell of my 2D array to have all properties defined by all other classes.

However, the issue is that I now have to provide those properties when populating the `map` for the first time.
This doesn't suit my need: I don't want my `Map` class to be aware of what other classes want to add. Each class should be responsible for filling in its data (and `Map` is responsible for initializing the `map` the first time so others can consider it available.)

The solution seems pretty simple to me: since the `CellData` properties aren't set when populating the map the first time, I have to say they are optional. And when a class wants to use it, it needs to check whether it's set or not.

Following this reasoning, I changed `Array<Array<CellData & MapCellData>>` to `Array<Array<Partial<CellData & MapCellData>>>`. (Just added `Partial`).

Now for the real issue: this does not work but there is no information on the error, I have no idea what I did wrong.
TypeScript simply states `Type '{ collides: true; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<CellData & MapCellData>'.`

Here is a complete example which produces the error:

```
interface CharacterManagerCellData {
  character: null | string;
}

interface CollisionCellData {
    collides: boolean;
}

// Directly using partial without generic works fine
type BasicCellData = Partial<CharacterManagerCellData & CollisionCellData>;

const myCell: BasicCellData = {
  collides: true
}

// Using the same pattern with a generic throws a typescript error
function myFunc<CellData extends object = {}>() {
  type RealCellData = Partial<CellData & CollisionCellData>;

  const cell: RealCellData = {
    collides: true
  }
}
```

I am using the latest version of TypeScript (3.6.3) and this error also occurs [in the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIAs5UZKBZOEOAc2lQgBsKAROMOZAbwFgAoZZBTbBXALmQgArlWQAfZAGcwUUMQDcbAL5s2oXPCRoA9lWCTg2kOSq16TNhw4JdFYABMIkgQCNtuiIUWsVrNgHp-ZGpgKAheCgBPZCEDEGJkAAcsMGA4CmQAd2AwdG0hMGRSEGhgBCztKABrSWQYUAg2MEjElAAhOAMEExo6BgBeZAAFFLSKAB4MLBxoAiJSKB6zBgAyHT0DIyW+gD5vNhsQaWQAW0iegQ6u7fNBlnZOWwcnARkhRp9VVkDkAFU4hK5FCSOAnFDJMC4EBZHLoZAMYqlcq5KDaTK1BjNVqSBCyRKFaCoqBsGBCEC8QzQs4AMTJCEmlF65ggAA9ICB7LVtC4AFbhQp3JQ7AAUAEoLA8sSgAEqeCg3AbDUbpBmmPrINaoJ6bYyM5Z7L7WIzHJBUASy9IK5B3SxWGx6RzOZBvD4cXxKIA)

Comment: Just as a side note, I'd avoid calling a class `Map`. Even though the compiler and JavaScript engine won't get confused, people reading and maintaining the code likely will. :-)

Comment: That is just bizarre.

Comment: Regarding the name, I understand your point. This is in a game context so it's not that confusing but I'm sad that those two names can mean such different things!

Comment: Yes, I was very surprised when I stumbled upon this. I thought I had made a mistake but it seems to be a TypeScript bug

Comment: It's a TypeScript... *something*. :-) I hesitate to call it a bug yet. Generics are tricky.

Comment: I'll wait a few days and open an issue if nobody is able to point a mistake on my part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript is not wrong about the error. You can never safely assign a concrete value to a generic type. Consider the following example:

```
myFunc<{ collides: false }>()
```

`collides` should be `false` not `true` considering to the passed in type, but you initialize it with `true`. This is obviously wrong. A generic function should be valid for **any** given `T`. This restriction means that instantiating an object and assigning it to a reference of a generic type is not usually possible (empty object is possible in this case because `Partial` makes everything optional regardless of type `const cell: RealCellData = {}`)

There are loopholes to this constraint, for example assignments are allowed, but for generic types if typescript can't be sure what the final type of the property is, it will not allow even simple assignments:

```
// this is better
function myFunc<CellData extends CollisionCellData >() {
  type RealCellData = Partial<CellData>;

  const cell: RealCellData = { //This is still an error
     collides: true
  } 
  cell.collides = true; // this is ok beacuse ts knows collide is boolean
}


//this is not ok 
function myFunc<CellData extends object >() {
  type RealCellData = Partial<CellData & CollisionCellData>;

  const cell: RealCellData = { //This is still an error
     collides: true
  } 
  cell.collides = true; // this is not ok, beacuse TS does not know if CellData has collides and what it's type may be
}
```

If you are ok with some types producing inconsistencies in your types, you can use a type assertion:

```
const cell = {
  collides: true
} as RealCellData
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=22&ssc=20&pln=20&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIAs5UZKBZOEOAc2lQgBsKAROMOZAbwFgAoZZBTbBXALmQgArlWQAfZAGcwUUMQDcbAL5s2oXPCRoA9lWCTg2kOSq16TNhw4JdFYABMIkgQCNtuiIUWsVrNgHp-ZGpgKAheCgBPZCEDEGJkAAcsMGA4CmQAd2AwdG0hMGRSEGhgBCztKABrSWQYUAg2MEjElAAhOAMEExo6BgBeZAAFFLSKAB4MLBxoAiJSKB6zBgAyHT0DIyW+gD5vNhsQaWQAW0iegQ6u7fNBlnZOWwcnARkhRp9VVkDkAFU4hK5FCSOAnFDJMC4EBZHLoZAMYqlcq5KDaTK1BjNVqSBCyRKFaCoqBsGBCEC8QzQs4AMTJCEmlF65ggAA9ICB7LVtC4AFbhQp3JQ7AAUAEoLA8sSgAEqeCg3AbDUbpBmmPrINaoJ6bYyM5Z7L7WIzHJCiO6WKw2PSOZzIN4fDhKeG1WXpBXKL40unjRiPa0vOrpSQoIVioA)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Would there be a way to "force" TypeScript to consider that `CellData` cannot touch the properties of `CollisionCellData`? My guess is that I could tell TS that `CellData` will never contain the `collides` property so that my `CollisionCellData` will always be the authority for that matter. (That's the goal I'd like to achieve)  
Something like `Partial<Omit<CellData, keyof CollisionCellData> & CollisionCellData>`

Comment: That doesn't work either but I have absolutely no idea why. From your answer, I understood that TypeScript was "scared" that `CellData` could contain something conflicting with `CollisionCellData` (like the `collides` property, in my example). In this case, why does the `Omit` not fix the issue? I expected `RealCellData` to always use the properties from `CollisionCellData` with no way to override it with `CellData`. This is very confusing

Comment: @Telokis What you want would require negated type (which are not supported, there is a proposal for those but we don't have them right now). `Omit` is just an application of mapped and conditional types, and TS generally is shy about drawing any information about a type such as `Omit<T, "collides">`. So this is not really possible .. only solution is a type assertion.

Comment: Ok, I guess I'll have to do it this way, then. The drawback doesn't seem too bad. Thanks for the answer.